Does detailed balance apply if electrons and ions have different temperatures
Suppose I have a plasma where the ion temperature $T_i$ is different from the electron temperature $T_e$. Does detailed balance still exist between recombination and ionization?

The system would not be at equilibrium. It is thus unlikely.

The only plasmas that exhibit $T_{i} = T_{e}$ are completely dominated by binary particle collisions.  Most plasmas in the universe (by volume) are not collisionally mediated, so they typically have $T_{i} \neq T_{e}$.  In fact, all plasmas we can measure with in situ data in space show each species has multiple populations (i.e., you cannot describe any velocity distribution as a single, isotropic Maxwellian).
